# Filling in 'gap rows' using an sql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with hourly values, similar to this:

```
|ID  |Date           |Value |
|1   |2016-1-1 01:00 |12    |
|2   |2016-1-1 02:00 |23    |
|3   |2016-1-1 03:00 |45    |  <-- Notice gap of 3 hours
|4   |2016-1-1 06:00 |12    |
|5   |2016-1-1 07:00 |3     |
```

I would like to call a procedure or sql that will fill these gaps with the respective date and a value of 0

Example output of procedure called at 07:15:

```
|Date           |Value |
|2016-1-1 01:00 |12    |
|2016-1-1 02:00 |23    |
|2016-1-1 03:00 |45    |
|2016-1-1 04:00 |0     |  <-- Notice gap now filled
|2016-1-1 05:00 |0     |  <-- Notice gap now filled
|2016-1-1 06:00 |12    |
|2016-1-1 07:00 |3     |
```

Preferably, I would also like it to fill any gaps up until the current hour. (e.g. If I called this procedure at 2016-1-1 05:15, It would include the gap rows 04:00 and 05:00.

While I don't have much of an attempt to share, I have attempted filling the gaps using a trigger before/after inserts, but have hit issues not allowing inserts/updates to occur on the triggered table (MySQL). Doing this programatically post-sql is possible but I would like to do this using sql if it is viable!

Comment: Why don't you leave this to Application Level?

Comment: Are you planning to call the procedure manually? I think if you prefer to call the procedure in every hour then it will be easier to handle. In this case you need to be concerned about only the last completed hour's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We are going to create a sample table to store hour wise data/value.
- Then we are going to create a procedure upon calling which checks if the last
  completed hour's data is present in the table.

  [Last completed hour means if
  the current time is 2016-02-12 13:10:53 then last completed hour is
  considered "2016-02-12 12:00:00".]
- If the last completed hour's data is present in the table then the
  procedure has nothing to do with that hour. Else the procedure
  inserts a row for last completed hour like below:

  > (Date,value) ("2016-02-12 12:00:00",0).

So here comes the implementations:

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `hourlyTable` (
`ID`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Date`  datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`value`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `HourlyProcedure`()
BEGIN
      DECLARE my_value INT DEFAULT -1;

              select `value` INTO my_value FROM hourlytable WHERE `Date` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00");

        IF my_value = -1 THEN
             INSERT INTO hourlytable 
                  SET `Date` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"),
                      `value` = 0;
        END IF;
END//
```

**Event:**
Next we are going to create an event which will trigger this procedure call in every hour's fifth minute.

```
CREATE EVENT `HourlyProcedureCallEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2016-02-12 13:05:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
CALL HourlyProcedure();
```

**Note:** You have to have `event_scheduler` `ON` in your MySQL server.
Here's the query to set `event_scheduler` `ON`.

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

**Further Notes:**

Being concerned only about the last completed hour's data is easier to handle.
But if you really want to fill multiple gaps by a stored procedure then the following procedure might be handy.

```
delimiter //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `MultipleGapFillerProcedure`(start INT,end INT)
BEGIN
      DECLARE my_value INT DEFAULT -1;

        label1 : 
            WHILE start <= end DO 
                        select `value` INTO my_value FROM hourlytable WHERE `Date` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL start HOUR,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00");

            IF my_value = -1 THEN
             INSERT INTO hourlytable 
                  SET `Date` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL start HOUR,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"),
                      `value` = 0;

            END IF;
            SET my_value = -1;
            SET start = start + 1;
        END WHILE label1;

END//
```

- If you call the MultipleGapFillerProcedure like this

  `CALL MultipleGapFillerProcedure(1,3)`;
- Then this procedure will try to insert last consecutive three hours
  data into the table (ONLY IF NOT EXISTS).
- Finally I think it's better to leave this task to your application
  level.

Comment: Thanks for answering Subrata!
Although, I believe I asked the question incorrectly.
I only need the gaps filled in the result of the select. (i.e. I don't need the data to persist in the table, I only need to fill the gaps in the resultset)
I have looked into a few similar questions and have tried my hand at left joining with temporary tables but haven't gotten very far other than a 40 second transaction.
Apologies for misleading you.